# R RMySQL Error could not find function fetch and unexpected input in dbConnect

Tags: r, fetch, rmysql

I'm trying to run this code on 3 machines:

```
install.packages("RMySQL")

connect_ciao = function() {
  return(dbConnect(
    MySQL(),
    user = user,
    password = pw,
    host = ip
  ))
}

query = "select 'ciao'" 
df = fetch(dbSendQuery(connect_ciao(), query), n = -1)
```

First machine works fine. 
Second machine (Mac, R version 3.5.1) gives error 
`could not find function "fetch"` 
Third machine (Mac, R version 3.5.3) gives error 
`unexpected input in "dbConnect(..."`

Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks,
Carlo

Comment: Assuming the code _and_ database are the same, then maybe there is a library/package error at work here.  Are you certain that all packages are the same on all 3 machines?

Comment: Hi! No, actually I'm not sure if library/package are the same. How can I verify? Shouldn't both fetch and dbConnect be included when I instal "RMySQL"?

Comment: Which begs the next question, are you sure that the same version of `RMySQL` was installed on all three machines?

Comment: You can call function from a specific function: `package::function()`. Also your other question try: `sessionInfo()` or `packageVersion("RMySQL")`

Comment: All machines have packageVersion("RMySQL") 0.10.17

Answer (score 0):

As Jav suggested, problem was solved by using RMySQL:: before each function from RMySQL.